# Access Control List in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I was wondering if there is any gem that implements an active admin control list in ActiveAdmin?

If none, what's the best way or  approach to simply do this?

Reading up on pundit and still active admin whether or not I should really write one from scratch.

Thanks!

Edit:
I currently worked on this yesterday and have my access control list together with my group model. the form looks roughly something like this:

[image]

its rendered partial in my activeadmin group.rb 
[image]

So yeah I guess the correct word is managing permissions on my activeadmin. I'm reading up if there is any way I can integrate activeadmin roles in my current setup. I'm kinda seeing this kind of setup is tedious?

I made it like this because eventually if there needs to be a lot of different roles, they don't have to ask the devs to code it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [ActiveAdminRole](https://github.com/yhirano55/active_admin_role)

Comment: should've seen this first! seems almost like something I intended to use or should've used in the first place. I'm editing my post with the current approach that I have to help me narrow down if the material you gave is still usable in my approach and to give me a heads up if I'd rather use the one you really sent